# Is this good practice for reading into a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, http

I have a function in C++ which reads the contents of a HTTP request **body** into a `std::string.`
I came up with the following code:

```cpp
void handle_request_body(int connfd, HttpRequest &req) {
  unsigned long size_to_read;
  try {
    size_to_read = std::stoul(req.headers().at("content-length"));
  } catch (std::out_of_range const &) {
    return;
  }
  char *buf = new char[size_to_read + 1];
  memset(buf, 0, size_to_read + 1);
  read(connfd, buf, size_to_read);
  req._body.append(buf);
  delete[] buf;
}
```

This is a little ugly to me as I have to use `new` since variable-sized arrays are not allowed.
I then tried to read directly to a string instead with the following code:

```cpp
void handle_request_body(int connfd, HttpRequest &req) {
  unsigned long size_to_read;
  try {
    size_to_read = std::stoul(req.headers().at("content-length"));
  } catch (std::out_of_range const &) {
    return;
  }
  std::string buf(size_to_read + 1, 0);
  read(connfd, buf.data(), size_to_read);
  req._body = buf;
}
```

I find the second method much cleaner, but I'm worried as to whether it is considered bad practice to read directly into a `std::string` using its `data()` method.

Is there a better way to do this?
Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Questions like this are often considered off-topic for being matters of opinion. Personally, using the `std::string` is the way to go IMO as it is no less safe than reading into the native char array and is more safe in other respects.

Comment: BTW, is `req._body` already a `std::string`? How is it initialized (and managed)? The first snippet *appends* the content of the buffer, while in the second you have `req._body = buf;`. My point is that you might use it directly, without introducing `buf`.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, `req._body` is a `std::string`. The reason why I introduced `buf` is because I needed to know how many bytes to read from the socket using the `content-length` header.

Comment: Well, it's still unclear to me why you don't just [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) the body, but I won't insist.

Comment: @Bob__ Ah, that's what you meant. Thank you for the suggestion! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really depends what your read function does under the hood.

If you have control over the read function, I strongly suggest you don't use a pointer, but rather a class reference to a std container.
The resizable std containers don't guarantee that the pointers will keep pointing at the same memory i.e. if it reallocates it's size, your pointer will no longer be valid. Which is fine in this example because no one else is touching it, but in a lot of other applications this would be extremely unsafe!

Something like:

```
void read(int id, std::string& dest, int readLength){
      //whatever code gets the data stream
      dest += data;
}
```

If it has to be a C-Style buffer for some OS API call probably best to use a unique pointer of chars, to let the memory clean up after itself.

```
 std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(size + 1);
 memset(&buffer[0], 0, size + 1);
```

I don't recommend reading from the OS char by char as this usually has a huge performance overhead for every call, compared to reading it all at once.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Indeed, `read` is a system call I'm using to read from the client socket. I didn't know about the method of using `std::unique_ptr`, I will try it out. One question, is `&buffer[0]` necessary or can I just use `&buffer`?

Comment: That's a great question, I'm not really sure to be honest. That will get the address of the class wrapping the char buffer, so it really depends if the memory is lined up so you can do that. I just use &buffer[0] because I know that will work, because buffer[0] gives you the reference to the first item, then I can just take the address to make a pointer.

I did try running &buffer and it crashed spectacularly, so I'm going to say no haha.

Answer (score 0):

As @Galik commented. This is opinion based.

But what we can state is:

- In C++ we should not use raw pointers for owned memory
- `new` and `delete` should be avoided
- C-Style arrays should be avoided
- Reading into `data()` will work, but is not that nice (my opinion). Anyway, better than using `new` and creating a memory leak.

You could, in a simple `for` loop read one byte after the other from the file and then add each byte to the `std::string` with `+=`. But this is also very clumsy.

Best would be, if you were allowed to use C++ language and libraries.

BTW. `std::string` is also a "variable-sized array"

Recommendation: Go with your second solution

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have thought of looping `size_to_read` times and appending byte by byte to `req._body` but thought it wasn't very elegant. This snippet is from a project where I'm attempting to make by own HTTP server library so I'm trying to do things "from scratch".
What I meant by "variable-sized arrays are not allowed" is an error I get from clangd
when trying to do `char buf[size_to_read + 1]`.
I'll stick to the second method then!